# What is `sudo apt-get clean`?

Tags: apt, disk-usage

When I get the message for a Software Update and click to install I get a message "Insufficienct space" telling me to empty trash and remove temporary files using `sudo apt-get clean`. I have emptied the trash but I still get the same message and don't know what temporary files to remove or what `sudo apt-get clean` is.

Comment: I don't know about the "sudo apt-get clean", but try using "sudo apt-get autoremove", it can also help getting some space

Comment: Was the dialog similar to [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1634) telling there is not enough space on '/boot'?

Comment: Please mark that you are affected by related [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1460396). You may also find useful information in its comments.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you are using? (Output of `lsb_release -r` in terminal)

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get clean` and emptying trash would probably not help , if your system has a separate partition for /boot.

Comment: Given that the question is not really "what is sudo apt-get clean" perhaps it can been renamed for future readers who might click on this question and be disappointed?

Answer (score 24):

`sudo apt-get clean` clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.It removes everything but the lock file from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.`

Source : `man apt-get`

Another possibility to see what happens when we use the command `sudo apt-get clean` is to simulate the execution with the `-s`-option.

```
~$ apt-get -s clean
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
```

```
~$ sudo apt-get -s clean
[sudo] password for mook: 
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
```

Thanks to @jarno for the suggestion.

Comment: You could simulate the command to show what it would do by running `apt-get -s clean` as regular user.  It seems to delete a couple of files in /var/cache/apt/ besides the above mentioned ones.

Comment: What is the so called `local repository` in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4):

If you receive the message "Insufficienct space" and the command `sudo apt-get clean` is insufficient, try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i   # (Allows you to execute commands with the privileges of the superuser.)       

KERNELCUR=$(uname -r | sed 's/-*[a-z]//g' | sed 's/-386//g')
PKGLINUX="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAPKGLINUX="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
KERNELSOLD=$(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E "$PKGLINUX" | grep -vE "$METAPKGLINUX" | grep -v "$KERNELCUR")

apt-get purge "$KERNELSOLD"   # (Remove old kernels.)

CONFOLD=$(dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')  

apt-get purge "$CONFOLD"   # (Removes configuration files from deb packages that have been uninstalled.)
apt-get autoremove   # (Deletes orphaned packages, or dependencies that remain installed after you have installed an application and then deleted it.)
apt-get clean   # (Removes all packets from the cache.)
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null   # (Empty the trash from all users.)
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null   # (Empty the trash from root.)
```

Comment: It would purge metakernel "linux-image-generic" in my system, if the depending kernel is not the current one thus preventing further kernel updates from being shown.

Comment: @Zanna: Your request has been made.

Comment: ... or, just apt autoremove && apt clean.